# Use JavaScript or Lodash to create multi dimensional array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to create a multi-dimensional array like this using Lodash or vanilla JS:

```
[
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
  etc
]
```

This is a simplistic example since I want this pattern to continue up to 1,000,000 but for demonstration 1 to 20 is fine.

Any ideas? I've tried `_.range(20)` so far but I need this Array to be multi-dimensional. Thanks

Comment: What happened when you tried `_.range(20)`? Perhaps you'd then be interested in [`_.chunk()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#chunk)

Comment: Pure JS: `Array.from(new Array(30)).map((_, i) => i + 1).reduce((acc, v) => v % 10 === 1 ? [...acc, [v]] : (acc[Math.floor((v - 1) / 10)].push(v), acc), [])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the **ES6** [**`Array.from`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) documentation you can see a **range generator function**:

> ```
> const range = (start, stop, step) => Array.from({ length: (stop -
> start) / step }, (_, i) => start + (i * step));
> ```

So with that in mind you could generate the range via:

```
range(1, 21, 1)  // account for the 0 with the 21 otherwise you get 1-19
```

Then all that is missing is the `chunk` function:

```js
const range = (start, stop, step) => Array.from({ length: (stop - start) / step }, (_, i) => start + (i * step));
const chunkBy = (arr, by=2) => arr.reduce((r,c,i) => (i%by==0 ? r.push([c]) : r[r.length-1] = [...r[r.length-1], c], r), [])

console.log(chunkBy(range(1,21,1), 10))
```

The `chunkBy` uses `Array.reduce` & the `%` operator to `chunk` the data.

Comment: And you wrote a mini lodash :D

Answer (score 6):

With lodash you can use [`chunk`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#chunk):

```js
const result = _.chunk(_.range(1, 21), 10);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just a minor correction... OP's arrays start at `1`

Comment: Upvote! First thing I though about when I read the question and then realized you already wrote it :)

Answer (score 5):

Using nested native `Array#from()`

```js
const 
   limit = 100,
   fr = Array.from;

const res = fr({ length:limit/10 }, (_,i) => fr({ length:10 }, (_,j) => i*10 + j+1 ));

console.log(res)
```

Comment: `Array#from()`  spot the Java dev ;-)

Comment: I know OP doesn't mention, but what if the `limit` isn't a multiple of 10, say 25? [Slider's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53403380/283366) handles that case via chunking

Comment: @Phil right...I assumed even 10's based on 20 and 1,000,000

Comment: It's not as pretty, but you could have something like `{length:Math.min(10, limit-(i*10))}` in the inside loop to handle non-even groupings.

Comment: @Akrion me too...never noticed that range generator example until I saw it in yours

Answer (score 3):

With vanilla javascript:

```js
x = []
for (i=1; i<=20; i=i+10) {
    y = []
    for (j=0; j<10; j++) {
        y.push(i + j)
    }
    x.push(y)
}
console.log(x)
```

For anyone who's interested, I time clocked these answers and this is the fastest. Using 1 million entries, this clocks at .100 seconds. Lodash chunk clocks close behind at .110s. `Array.from` lags behind at .254s.

Comment: @Phil hah, fixed... and time-clocked